# How can I test if my observed PDF follows a binomial distribution?

Tags: r, distributions, binomial-distribution

I have got an observed PDF and I would like to test if it fits well a binomial distribution, i.e. if I can affirm that my observed data follow a binomial distribution.

I am using R, is there any package that can help me doing so?

The picture shows my observed PDF in bold black and a theoretical binomial distribution.

[image]

Comment: Do a chi-squared test.

Comment: I keep an [anonymous site with notes](http://rinterested.github.io/statistics/chi_square_GOF.html), and I wonder if example 7 in the link fits your question. Let me know...

Comment: You can also use the R package `fitdistrplus` as in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27778510/4089351).

Comment: @David A chi-squared test will have low power against smooth deviations compared to other alternatives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get p-value from fidistrplus](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278452/get-p-value-from-fidistrplus)

Comment: What would be cool is if you calculated the KL divergence between the two, although that would not give you an interpretable number, you could compute the KL divergence to a bunch of named distributions and take the min :)

Answer (score 8):

Please note that this question is duplicated, and there is a [better answer by Glen_b over here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/278455/67822).

---

Here is an example using the the R package `fitdistrplus`. The simulated data is strictly binomial, and hence we should fail to reject the null hypothesis.

```
require("fitdistrplus")
set.seed(10)
n = 25
size = 27
prob = .4
data = rbinom(n, size = size, prob = prob)
fit = fitdist(data = data, dist="binom", 
                   fix.arg=list(size = size), 
                   start=list(prob = 0.1))

summary(fit)
Fitting of the distribution ' binom ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters : 
      estimate Std. Error
prob 0.3822225 0.01870338
Fixed parameters:
     value
size    27
Loglikelihood:  -52.24948   AIC:  106.499   BIC:  107.7178 

plot(fit)
```

[image]

This estimation of the probability of success ($\Pr(S) = 0.38$) is very close to $\Pr(S) =0.4$ set up when the data was generated. However, you are not just estimating the parameter, but also the distribution, as Glen_b explains on the parallel post:

> ... not only are you estimating parameters (which may be able to be dealt with - some tests adapt to that more or less easily) but frequently you're also selecting between several choices of distributional model.

You may want, therefore, to contrast the result with other distributions. For example here is the output selecting a Poisson distribution:

```
fit2 = fitdist(data, dist = "pois")
summary(fit2)
plot(fit2)
Fitting of the distribution ' pois ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters : 
       estimate Std. Error
lambda    10.32  0.6424951
Loglikelihood:  -55.95267   AIC:  113.9053   BIC:  115.1242
```

Predictably, the AIC increases: we have set up the data as binomial, so it would be expected that the better fitting distribution (lower AIC) is binomial, and not Poisson. Here are the corresponding plots:

### [image]

Notice that we have to supply the probability of success to then estimate the goodness of fit. In the simulation above, we asked `fitdistrplus()` to start estimating MLE from a value of $\small \Pr(\text{success})=0.1$.

If we were to run a chi square goodness of fit test we could try several values. Here is a simulation with the same dataset as above:

```
par(mfrow = c(1,3))
obs.counts  = table(factor(data, levels = 0:27)) # Tabulated results of dataset
plot(obs.counts,"h",  col = "turquoise", main = "Obs'd counts", cex.main = .9)
values = seq(0.3, 0.7, 0.1) # P(S) chosen (.3,.4,.5,.6,.7)
targ.freq = matrix(0, length(values), size + 1)  # Starting an empty matrix
# PMF for different p (Prob) values:
for(i in 1:length(values)) targ.freq[i,] = dbinom(0:size, size = size, prob = values[i]) 
plot(targ.freq[1,], type = "l", col = "darkblue", 
main = "Exp'd freq", cex.main = .9, ylab = 'Freq', xlab="")
for(i in 1:nrow(targ.freq)) lines(targ.freq[i,], col = "darkblue")
for(i in 1:nrow(targ.freq)) text(which.max(targ.freq[i,]), 
                                 max(targ.freq[i,] + .005), values[i],
                                 col= "darkblue")
exp.counts = matrix(0, length(values), size + 1) # Starting empty matrix
# Calculating expected counts...
for(i in 1:nrow(targ.freq)) exp.counts[i,]  = round(targ.freq[i,] * length(data)) 
colnames(exp.counts) = 0:size
vec = c(1,3,5)
matplot(t(exp.counts)[ ,vec],type="h",col=c(2:nrow(exp.counts)+1),lty=1,
        ylab ="Exp. counts", main = "Exp counts 3 Pr(S)")
lab = values[c(1,3,5)]
x.positions = c(7,15,22)
for(i in 1:nrow(targ.freq)) text(x.positions[i], 
                            max(exp.counts[i,] + .1), lab[i], col= "darkblue")
```

The expected frequencies and counts (and consequentially the fit to the observed data) will change with the different probabilities of success (on the right plot only three of them were plotted):

[image]

Likewise, the p values of the GOF chi square will show a peak around the probability we set up in the generation of the data:

```
p.values = NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(targ.freq)) p.values[i] = chisq.test(obs.counts , p = targ.freq[i,])$p.value
par(mfrow = c(1,1))
plot(values, p.values, type = "h", main = "Chi square p values", cex.main = .8)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much. regarding the fitdist example, why you set start=list(prob = 0.1) ?

Comment: in other words, I don't understand the start argument and eventually the relative probability that needs to be specified.

Comment: and also, how can I get the p-value from fitdist? thanks