# Get p-value from fitdistrplus

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, distributions, p-value, goodness-of-fit

Starting from this question [How can I test if my observed PDF follows a binomial distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278344/how-can-i-test-if-my-observed-pdf-follows-a-binomial-distribution)

I have got the following binomial distribution:

```
require("fitdistrplus")
set.seed(10)
n = 25
size = 27
prob = .4
data = rbinom(n, size = size, prob = prob)
fit = fitdist(data = data, dist="binom", 
                   fix.arg=list(size = size), 
                   start=list(prob = 0.1))

summary(fit)
Fitting of the distribution ' binom ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters : 
      estimate Std. Error
prob 0.3822225 0.01870338
Fixed parameters:
     value
size    27
Loglikelihood:  -52.24948   AIC:  106.499   BIC:  107.7178
```

Is there any way I can get the p-value from the `fitdist` function?
Or is the p-value `prob 0.3822225`?

In other words I desire to know if I can state with high level of certainty that my empirical data follow a binomial distribution

Comment: I don't think you get a p-value as such (not sure what that would mean, unless you had an alternative hypothesis), but the three figures in the final line of output are related to the goodness of fit.  It would be sensible to test a number of different distributions in order to demonstrate that binomial is best.

Comment: thank you, the thing is that I can also plot the empirical and theoretical dist by doing plot(fit). In this way I can check visually the two distributions, but does exist a number (p-value or similar) that can state clearly: YES, YOUR EMPIRICAL DIST BELONGS TO A BINOMIAL. thanks

Comment: I think this should go to CV, as it is not primarily a programming question. As to the question, if there are indeed two plausible distributions that the data could originate from (and in many cases, this is a big'n'bold if), goodness of fit statistics are probably what you are after, but I think people over at CV will have more informed opinions on that.

Comment: You seem to be assuming a binomial distribution and then estimate the probability of success parameter and not testing whether or not the data fits a binomial.

Comment: Although this is asking about R code in a way that would ordinarily be off topic here, this question is based on a statistical misunderstanding that we can / should clear up. As such, it is on topic. I'm voting to leave open.

Comment: This is a note about R usage, and not the actual statistical methodology, but...
If your code will fail later when a particular package is not installed, you should use `library` instead of `require`, because `require` can silently fail to load your package. `require` should only be used to load optional, or conditionally optional packages.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "prob" value there is the estimate of the $p$ parameter of a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function). It is not a p-value.

To get a p-value, you need to specify a null hypothesis (at least) and typically an alternative (with goodness of fit, the space of alternatives you're interested in may in part define/guide the kind of test you would do, for example if you're doing a likelihood ratio test).

[However, it is possible to base a test directly off the likelihood under the null.]

There are several issues with performing a test of a distribution you're estimating -- for example not only are you estimating parameters (which may be able to be dealt with - some tests adapt to that more or less easily) but frequently you're also selecting between several choices of distributional model. That impacts the properties of any common test you might want to do.

There are a wide variety of goodness of fit tests, but they're usually not especially useful (in particular they're often used in situations where they don't really address the problem people want them to solve). [The package `fitdistrplus` offers a function, `gofstat` which computes several goodness of fit statistics.]

> I desire to know if I can state with high level of certainty that my empirical data follow a binomial distribution

Even if you can get a p-value, *it cannot tell you that*. You can't determine to a high level of certainty that your sample *does* come from some distribution since non-binomial distributions can be arbitrarily close to binomial distributions -- there's always room between the data and the distribution you fit to have one that's very like a binomial but a better fit to the data.

Failure to reject a binomial doesn't mean you have a binomial.

Comment: I'd recommend you wait at least a day, if you're able.

Comment: @aaaaa On your particular data `summary(fitdist(data = data, dist="norm"))` may seem to give a better fit than the fixed size binomial in terms of Loglikelihood, AIC and BIC, though it benefits from a second free parameter and is clearly implausible since a normal distribution is unlikely to generate $25$ integers

Comment: The OP copies and pastes my code on a simultaneous post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/278395/67822), keeping both posts going :-) One benefit of this "promiscuous" behavior is that I got to learn from your answer, just when I was about to edit my post talking about comparing AIC values between different distributions, etc. I realize that this other hybrid post was intended for SO.SE. although it wouldn't have  been too unreasonable for him/her to set up a link, or something... :-)

Comment: I will add immediately a link referring to my original question. sorry about that.

Comment: and if you could explain why you set prob = 0.1 it would be great, thanks and again sorry.

Comment: @aaaaa No problem. I have split my questions at times with code-specific issues going to SO, and the more conceptual stuff going to CV. It's great to get Glen_b's take on your question - he had already left a comment for you on the original question re: the power of the chi square GOF, and I was actually hoping for his input. So it all worked out well. Perhaps both posts could be combined into one. I'll be happy to erase my initial answer if convenient.

Comment: @aaaaa I have edited my original post. I hope there is nothing misleading. If nothing else, the manual set up for the chi square may put some emphasis on the need to provide a probability of "success" value (as well as `size`). Unfortunately I don't know more about the need to set up a starting probability, but the MLE procedure in fitdist() relies on testing different probabilities, and therefore it is not surprising that the function happens to ask for a starting point.

Comment: Glen, I posted a link to this answer on my own initial answer, and voted to close the other post. I don't know if there is a way to migrate my answer here. If you think it's best I'll delete it, or leave it with a likely to-be-soon-closed post. BTW, I'll erase all this clutter of comments after your read them. Or you can erase them as you go through them (?). Ty!

Comment: @Antoni From my recollection of the other post (which I haven't seen since I left a comment), I hadn't even considered that it would be seen as very similar to this one. Did it change or did I just misremember its content? In any case I would be suprised if there was anything to gain by deleting your effort. I'll try to take a look at it shortly to see if there's a reason to merge them (which would move the answers all to one post).

Comment: @Glen_b OK, Glen, do as you see fit - you'll see how my answer to the other post points to yours with deference. Best wishes, Toni

Comment: @antoni If you have any thoughts on a better title for this Q, please consider editing it.

Comment: @Glen_b I'm completely satisfied, and learned a lot from your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @Antoni I am going to see if I can edit parts of this question into the one you answered, with the aim of merging this question into the one you answered (which I think is the better place for things to end up). It may take a while to sort it out.